how can I conditionaly include different assembly .asm files based on a define example if linux os include linux.asm else include windows.asm
I have an app that uses multiple static libraries that use NASM as the assembler and compiles in Linux and android and all builds are done with CMake only. They all compile fine and I did conditional includes of assembly files using the NASM -P option. For example in CMake
if(DEFINED TARGET_OS_ANDROID)
    #android/aarch64 uses clang as assembler
elseif(DEFINED TARGET_OS_WINDOWS)
    enable_language(ASM_NASM)
    string(APPEND CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS "-Pconfig_ffmpeg_w64.asm ")
else()
    enable_language(ASM_NASM)
    string(APPEND CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS "-Pconfig_ffmpeg_linux.asm ")
endif()

I want to compile using flatpak for Linux distribution but the -P no longer works (I assume flatpak overrides it for their own use).
Is there a way to conditionally include asm files like above but inside a asm file using a if defined to simulate what I did in CMake?
Using scripts to generate the asm file before the compile is NOT an option.
Repo checkout is git clone https://gitlab.com/nolimitconnectapps/nolimitapp.git
I expected it to more or less compile in flatpak because it is a Linux environment but no joy.
Tried just including all the asm defines in root CMakeList.txt using similar to
add_compile_definitions(HAVE_SYMVER_GNU_ASM=1)

but some libraries require different values so for example maybe HAVE_SYMVER_GNU_ASM should be 0 in another library and this causes many issues.

NASM has an %include directive as well as %ifdef or numeric %if (and the corresponding %else and %endif). Then you can use the -D switch to set up defines for the %if to check. However, NASM must be able to find an included file either starting from the current working directory, or using -I switches to NASM.

ecm - thank you for the answer. It seems exactly what I was looking for. My workaround was messy - and all of the defines required using
if(DEFINED FLATPAKBUILD)
target_compile_definitions(avcodec
PRIVATE
#it seems the nasm -P does not work in flatpak so add all the defines here for ffmpeg etc.
ARCH_AARCH64=0
+ 600 more defines
}
in the cmake files but this means that if any one value changes it has to be changed in 5 CMakeLists.txt files
